# jQuery Mobile Filtered List - only match beginning of string

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im using the jQuery mobile search filter list: 
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-performance.html

Im having somer performance issues, my list is a little slow to filter on some phones. To try and aid performance I want to change the search so only items starting with the search text are returned.

So 'aris' currently finds the result 'paris' but I want this changed. I can see its possible from the documentation below but I dont know how to implement the code.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

```
$("document").ready( function (){
  $(".ui-listview").listview('option', 'filterCallback', yourFilterFunction)
});
```

This seems to demonstrate how you write and call your own function, but ive no idea how to write it! Thanks 
http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/02/14/jquery-mobile-tip-write-your-own-list-view-filter-function/

UPDATE - Ive tried the following in a seperate js file:

```
$("document").ready( function (){

  function beginsWith( text, pattern) {
  text= text.toLowerCase();
  pattern = pattern.toLowerCase();

  return pattern == text.substr( 0, pattern.length );
  }

  $(".ui-listview").listview('option', 'filterCallback', beginsWith)

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might look something like this:

```
function beginsWith( text, pattern) {
text= text.toLowerCase();
pattern = pattern.toLowerCase();

return pattern == text.substr( 0, pattern.length );
}
```

Basically you compare from 0 to "length" of what you're matching to the source. So if you pass in "test","tester" it will see you're passing in a string of length **4** and then substr "tester" from 0,4, which gives you "test". Then "test" is equal to "test"... so return true. Lowercase them to make it case insensitive.

Another trick to improve filter performance, only filter once they've entered more than 1 character.

**edit** it appears jQueryMobile's filter function expects that "true" means it was not found... so it needs to be backwards. `return pattern != text.substr( 0, pattern.length );`

Comment: Ive updated my question with how I implemented your code but it didnt work. Im surprised this isnt a standard answer somewhere in the documentation, given that the documentation mentions its possible.

Comment: I don't really know what the function is expecting as arguments, I was just giving you the general idea... but could it be that you have an extra **1** in your function name... i.e. `beginsWith1` instead of `beginsWith`

Comment: Sorry, I temporarily added the 1 to disable the code. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction but my js isnt good enough to figure this out. Ill keep looking for a blog post and in the documentation. Im sure other people have done what Im after so hopefully Ill find a tutorial.

Comment: I dunno, it looks right, can you create a JSFiddle for me? I think it should work just fine.

Comment: OHH, sometimes `document.ready` doesn't work for jQueryMobile... you need to bind to the pageInit event instead. See http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html  and also see http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: OHHHHHHHH! Again... one more thing... looks like from the docs: *"A truthy value will result in a hidden list item"* means that it needs to be "!=" instead of "==".

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I am using regular expression here so sort of different way to achieve the same thing.

But the reason why my code didn't work initially was that the list item had a lot of spaces at the beginning and at the end (found that it got added on it's own while debugging).

So I do a trim on the text before doing the match. I have a feeling Jonathan Rowny's implementation will also work if we do text.trim() before matching.

```
 $(".ui-listview").listview('option', 'filterCallback', function (text, searchValue) {

    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + searchValue, "i");

    return !matcher.test(text.trim());
});
```